# Asynchronous job execution and job state management using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, design-patterns, asynchronous

I am looking for a design pattern to execute a list of jobs queued up in a table, asynchronously and also update the job status in the database (completed/failed/cancelled). preferably I should be able to kill a job as well on user demand just in case the job takes more time to execute than expected or if the user kicked off the job mistakenly. each of these jobs take a while to execute.

I can have a windows service which monitors the table for any new jobs and then use multi-threading to execute them asynchronously. but multi-threading is complex and error-prone. will using WCF services be helpful in anyway for this purpose? for example instead of multi-threading, can I have a WCF service to execute the jobs and call it asynchronously and then subscribe to its completed event to update the job status? which option is better or it doesn't really matter? as I said I need to be able to cancel the job as well if required.

Comment: Why the need to execute them in parallel as opposed to FIFO? This just adds complexity if you don't need it.

Comment: because they are independent and running in parallel saves time

Comment: And must the queue be processed on a separate machine, separate process? E.g. is resilience very important? I ask because often I see complex standalone queue processors being implemented and hosted in Windows services (which are usually a deployment nightmare) when a background thread in the client process would do.

Comment: here I should be able to execute the jobs through automation with no GUI and also on user demand. no separate machine or process. all the processing should be done on one machine on separate threads. if you are referring to the .NET backgroundworker component, then it is only applicable if the thread is launched from UI. but in my case the windows service may also start the jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). It facilitates seemingly everything you need, with the only real complexity coming in where you need to feed the jobs to your factory, so to speak.

<sub>Apologies for such a short answer with no examples, I'm both on my phone and trying to eat.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The design pattern is [Producer Consumer Queue](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=producer%20consumer%20queue).

If you are implementing the queue as a data structure, then you need to use a thread-safe queue.

If you are using a database table to implement the queue, then use the atomicity of the DBMS to make sure only one consumer grabs a particular item from the queue.